# Google Script Request to App Store Connect Error

Tags: google-apps-script, jwt, app-store-connect, http-status-code-401

I wrote the code in Google Script, when I run it I get an error:

```
{
    "errors": [{
        "status": "401",
        "code": "NOT_AUTHORIZED",
        "title": "Authentication credentials are missing or invalid.",
        "detail": "Provide a properly configured and signed bearer token, and make sure that it has not expired. Learn more about Generating Tokens for API Requests https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=api-generating-tokens"
    }]
}
```

The generated token from the script is formed with the correct headers, but warning with Invalid Signature, I checked it here - https://jwt.io/
Looks like problem in when signature is incoded.

Here is code:

```
const createJwt = ({ privateKey, expiresInMins, data = {} }) => {
  // Sign token using HMAC with SHA-256 algorithm
  const header = {
    alg: 'ES256',
    kid: '**kid**',
    typ: 'JWT'
  };

  const now = Date.now();
  const expires = new Date(now);
  expires.setMinutes(expires.getMinutes() + expiresInMins);

  // iat = issued time, exp = expiration time
  const payload = {
    exp: Math.round(expires.getTime() / 1000),
    iat: Math.round(now / 1000),
  };

  // add user payload
  Object.keys(data).forEach(function (key) {
    payload[key] = data[key];
  });

  const base64Encode = (text, json = true) => {
    const data = json ? JSON.stringify(text) : text;
    return Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(data).replace(/=+$/, '');
  };

  const toSign = `${base64Encode(header)}.${base64Encode(payload)}`;
  const signatureBytes = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(toSign, privateKey);
  const signature = base64Encode(signatureBytes, false);
  return `${toSign}.${signature}`;
};

  const generateAccessToken = () => {
  // Your super secret private key
  const privateKey = '**private key**';
  const accessToken = createJwt({
    privateKey,
    expiresInMins: 10,
    data: {
      iss: '**iss**',
      aud: 'appstoreconnect-v1'
    },
  });
  Logger.log(accessToken);
  
  getUsers(accessToken);

};

function getUsers(accessToken){
    url = 'https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/users';

    const optionsUsrGet = {
      method: 'GET',
      muteHttpExceptions: true,
      contentType: "application/json",
      headers: {
        'Authorization': "Bearer " + accessToken}
    };

    const responseUsrGet = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, optionsUsrGet);
    if (responseUsrGet.getResponseCode() !=200 ) {
     Logger.log(responseUsrGet);
     service.reset();
      fail;
    };

    const data = JSON.parse(responseUsrGet);
    Logger.log(data);
}
```

Updated:

In general, a key in .p8 format is downloaded from App Store Connect something like this:

-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGTAgEAMBMDByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBHkwdwIBAQQgnUaBH3umCqbyl6w4
NBE9YxD42J2AFBXjfd8+tvVOQrOgCgYIKoZIzj1OPQehASVSAAS4fh1BhWSzj0PV
vgIIllp9BQZKTNopsesddJ5ofmKYO/m7al9Pk1KAvN0vQRJKyHJ8A0sJUc0bljDSTm
GwBK4LPo
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

In the description, the key should be encrypted with the ES256 algorithm (ECDSASha256), judging by
all over Google Scripts Can only RsaSha256 or HmacSha256, it turns out
that line: const signatureBytes = Utilities.computeRsaSha256Signature(toSign, privatekey)
Signs the data incorrectly, which is why I can’t connect via the Apple API.

I took the RSA PKCS#8 test key:

-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBVAIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAT4wggE6AgEAAkEAqPfgaTEWEP3S9w0t
gsicURfo+nLW09/0KfOPinhYZ4ouzU+3xC4pSlEp8Ut9FgL0AgqNslNaK34Kq+NZ
jO9DAQIDAQABAkAgkuLEHLaqkWhLgNKagSajeobLS3rPT0Agm0f7k55FXVt743hw
Ngkp98bMNrzy9AQ1mJGbQZGrpr4c8ZAx3aRNAiEAoxK/MgGeeLui385KJ7ZOYktj
hLBNAB69fKwTZFsUNh0CIQEJQRpFCcydunv2bENcN/oBTRw39E8GNv2pIcNxZkcb
NQIgbYSzn3Py6AasNj6nEtCfB+i1p3F35TK/87DlPSrmAgkCIQDJLhFoj1gbwRbH
/bDRPrtlRUDDx44wHoEhSDRdy77eiQIgE6z/k6I+ChN1LLttwX0galITxmAYrOBh
BVl433tgTTQ=
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

In this case, everything is signed, but the key is not from App Store Connect.

JWT with key from AppStore Connect:
eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ik8xREszMUIyUkQiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJleHAiOjE2OTk2MTA2MzEsImlhdCI6MTY5OTYxMDAzMSwiaXNzIjoiM2NvcDMyMTYtZD kyMS00YTU0LWEyZTUtN2o5MTc4Yjg5YWMzIiwiYXVkIjoiYXBwc3RvcmVjb25uZWN0LXYxIn0.F1wiu601YWLL3ZXPTu8f_m-ggTqeVavihye_ToesaJs

Required to get a list of users from App Store Connect via API

Comment: About `The generated token from the script is formed with the correct headers`, can we consider that your `accessToken` is a valid value? And, can you provide the official document of your API for understanding the specifications of the API?

Comment: Hello! I'm using this manual - https://www.labnol.org/code/json-web-token-201128
I think the problem in signature encode part. I'm download key from App Store Connect in .p8 format. Key start with "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----". 

Here is App Store Connect JWT Token instruction - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/generating_tokens_for_api_requests

Comment: I also tried this - https://nima-poulad-40744.medium.com/jwt-tokens-and-google-app-script-79c3948dc57c
But when i'm use my key, recived error - "Invalid argument: key"

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your answer to my question of `About The generated token from the script is formed with the correct headers, can we consider that your accessToken is a valid value?`. Can I ask you about it?

Comment: Thank you for trying to help! What do you mean by AccesToken? If you about token which i get from App Store it is correct one, becouse when i'm use it in Postman with same parametres it's work perfect.

Comment: The token has the correct values, but there is clearly a problem with the signature part.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `What do you mean by AccesToken?`, it's `accessToken` in your showing script. From `The generated token from the script is formed with the correct headers`, first, I would like to have confirmed whether your access token was a valid access token.

Comment: i'm Updated body of the question

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot test your script. But, I would like to support you. When I could find a solution, I would like to propose it. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your issue soon. I think that this is due to my very poor skill. I have to apologize for my very poor skill.